# Why does the standard state that there are three possible name spaces for tags of structures, enums and unions in C, while they actually only got one?

Tags: c, struct, enums, namespaces, unions

In ISO/IEC 9899:2018(C18), 6.2.3 "Name spaces of identifiers" is stated (emphasize mine):

> 6.2.3    Name spaces of identifiers
>
> 1 If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities. Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> - label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
> - the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any32) of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
> - the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the member via the . or -> operator);
> - all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).
>
>   ---
>
> 32) There is **only one** name space for tags **even though three are possible**.

What do they mean with "*even though three are possible.*" What is this "possible" exactly?

---

As experiment I tried to compile the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct foo{
        int a;
        double b;
        float c;
    };

    enum foo{
        Test1,Test2,Test3
    };

    union foo{
        int x;
        double y;
        float z;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

I´ve got the error of:

> error: ‘foo’ defined as wrong kind of tag

for both, the `enum` and the `union` definition like you can see [here](https://ideone.com/FrP1IB) as well, which proofs that only one name space is provided for all `struct`, `enum` and `union` tags defined at the same scope, like the standard described it. But what about these other two "possible" name spaces?

My question is:

- Why does the standard state that there are three possible name spaces for tags of structures, enums and unions in C, when they actually only have one (at the same scope)?

And why can´t we use the three possible name spaces for tags of structs, enums and unions although even the standard says that they shall exist?

Comment: All tag names belong to one category of namespaces.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Unfortunately yes, but why we can´t we use the potential of the other two if they exist?

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  The standard does cite it that way. Why am I not allowed to ask for that?

Comment: It is not me who down-voted your question. As for me then I can up-vote it. No problem.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I did not "pinged" you especially. :-) Just because of someone did it earlier. Is it normally that commentators get "ping"ed automatically when new comments are made? I was not aware of that.

Comment: Here is one more similar situation with a question at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299279/finding-the-last-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-sentence-in-c/60300659#60300659

Comment: And my own good answers are very often down-voted or ignored only by one reason: because I am from Russia.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, I got no problem with that. The best answer shall be the best answer. Good answers shall be up-voted. I see no reason for not doing so. It seems that the community is sometimes a little bit to critical, facing that this is a Q&A platform, not a noble-prize party.

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not say that separate name spaces exist for structures, unions, and enumerations. It says that theoretically three are possible, meaning the language could have been designed to have separate name spaces for each.

The language could have been designed to have separate name spaces because the tags appear only after a keyword `struct`, `union`, or `enum`, so a compiler would always know which name space were needed.

Nonetheless, the C developers and the C committee decided not to use this in the language design. The meaning of the standard is that there is one name space that contains all tags of structures, unions, and enumerations.

Comment: I understand "possible" in *even though three are possible.* as that they are implemented practically not just theoretically but we just can´t use them. Do you got any reference from the committee at which the statements become clearer?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: What do you mean “they are implemented practically not just theoretically”? They are not implemented.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: The passage you cite is clear. The introductory statement says “Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows.” What follows is then a list with four items, each item marked with a “—” and separated by vertical spacing from the other items. So it is clear that each of the items in the lists is one of the name spaces introduced by that statement. The second item is “The *tags* of structures, unions and enumerations…” So it is clear that the tags of all three form one name space.

Comment: I mean that this phrase (in my humble opinion) implies that 3 namespaces shall be provided in any conform implementation but we just can´t use those three separate name spaces.

Comment: Also note that the third item explicitly says each structure or union has a separate name space for its members. The second item has no such qualification that says there are separate name spaces, reinforcing that it is just one name space. (Originally, C had only one name space for members of unions and structures; if you defined a structure type containing a member `b`, it appeared in the same location in all other structure types.)

Comment: I know that it is one name space for all of them in the same scope - this is fact - We can´t change nothing at all about this, but my intention is to find out what happens with the other two name spaces (if they shall be implemented) and why can´t we use them - just out of curiosity.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: Your phrasing is not making sense. Nothing happens with the other two name spaces. Compilers are not written to implement them. When a compiler sees a tag after a `struct`, `union`, or `enum` keyword`, it looks up the tag in one database it mains for the tag names. That is all.