# What is the rationale for only one name space for tags?

Tags: c, namespaces, language-lawyer

C11, footnote 32 (emphasis added):

> There is only **one name space for tags** even though **three are possible**.

Rationale doesn't give the rationale (emphasis added):

> The position adopted in the Standard is to permit as many separate name spaces as can be distinguished by context, except that **all tags** (struct, union, and enum) **comprise a single name space**.

The similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60127170/1778275) has this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60127203/1778275) (fragment, emphasis added):

> Nonetheless, the C developers and the C committee **decided not to use this** in the language design.

A simple question: what is the rationale?

Comment: Lack of utility, opportunity for error (people do not much need separate name spaces for these, and having them would result in occasional errors of using `struct foo` where `union foo` was needed).

Comment: IIRC in C++ if you declare `struct foo` it automatically defines a type `foo` and similar for `union` and `enum`. That would cause problems if you allow for `struct foo` and `union foo`. Maybe the C standard guys didn't want to create another incompatibility.